# Использование if else в render

Tags: reactjs, render

Возник вопрос относительно использования if else conditions в функции render.
Узнал из React.js up and running, что библиотека берет на себя работу с нативным выбором элементов на странице и изменением их свойств.

А точнее делает это таким образом:

1) за счет изменений состояний, вызванных с помощью наших описаний, изменяет структуру виртуального DOM

2) определяет наилучший момент для перестроения реального DOM-дерева

3) перестраивает его

Работает ли этот подход при использовани  if else statements в функции render()? Или где можно подробнее узнать о правилах механизма перестроения DOM, чтобы использовать эту возможность библиотеки по максимуму?

В качестве листинга - простой пример со списком контактов, изменение состояния заключается в добавлении развернутого описания из e-mail и адреса при клике на пункте.

```
toggleState() {
    this.setState({isOpened: !this.state.isOpened});
  }

render() {
    let dropdownInfo;
    if (this.state.isOpened) {
      dropdownInfo = <div className="dropdown-info">
        <div className="contact-email">{this.props.email}</div>
        <div className="contact-adress">{this.props.adress}</div>
      </div>
    }
    return (
        <li className="contact" onClick={this.toggleState.bind(this)}>
          <img className="contact-image" src={this.props.image}/>
          <div className="contact-info">
            <div className="contact-number">{this.props.phoneNumber}</div>
            {dropdownInfo}
          </div>
        </li>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Работает и `if` и `switch` и тернарный оператор и все остальные возможности JS, т.к. render это обычная функция javascript.

Comment: Спасибо. Это я понял. Больше интересует, наужна ли какая-то специальная структура в функции render, чтобы библиотека оптимально перестраивала DOM-дерево, или это в любом случае выполняется автоматически?

Comment: @MaxBender любые структуры будут работать одинаково. Для оптимизации есть метод shouldComponentUpdate https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate